# Which design pattern should I use for taking query parameters and combining them to create a filtered sql query

Tags: sql, url, design-patterns, filter

If I have a url that can take a large number of parameters that I then want to mix and match on the fly to create sql queries to return results...

Which design patterns could I consider to create filters from parameters?

example:

mySite.com?name=tom&color=red&size=large&etc

desired sql output
select * from mytable where name = tom and color = red and size = large;

This is trivial in the small but when you have a large set of variable parameters coming from a filter panel that includes dates and match query strings etc and you want to tidily and maintainably assemble them into sql queries, all the while checking and cleaning the data, things can get err.. verbose. I've ended up writing tonnes of if/else style filter methods which is a bit of a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Can you clarify your Scenario please? In particular, can you be more specific about the create filter from param part. As for building queries, you can use a [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html).

Comment: Can't you just fill a map with the parameter's name and value?

Comment: To clarify... an sql database made up of a number of tables related via foreign keys. a large number of parameters passed in via the url, most of which are optional. I need to mix and match those parameters into sql (including joins and such) before finally passing the generated sql off to be executed and results returned. @Rex is suggesting decorator pattern in his answer which is looking promising I must say. I could start with a base query and 'decorate' the various conditions pulled from the url onto the base query perhaps...

Comment: @stan0 too complex for just key value mappings as in some cases joins are needed, in some cases not. Also, I want to be able to check the input in almost every case and do various translations eg. url param might be &timeofday=afternoon but the query needs to be time_of_day_id = 3 or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this kind of scenarios, i like to use decorator pattern where you can dynamically build/mix up "ingredients".

i think the wikipedia does have a good sample of this (the coffee making scenario): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: So would you then start with a base query that you then decorate with more conditions for the query?

Comment: yes, sort of. for complex scenarios such as joins and etc., might need another base class for each type of joins. and to make it easy to use, probably you want to mix it up with Facade and Factory patterns